# ElasticSearch Query to pass python dynamic variable

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

```
res = es.search(index="resume", body={"query": {"match" : {"resume_file_text" : '"+key+"'}}})
```

How pass the variable 'key' it holds the value given by user at UI and changes dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

The body is a hash not a string (so no need to concat anything). So you can do it like this:

```
res = es.search(index="resume", body={"query": {"match" : {"resume_file_text" : key}}})
```

Comment: Thank you..It's Working.